# db.create_all() in create_app() don`t work

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The error is `'No application found. Either work inside a view function or push'
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.`

My create_app() is :

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
app.config.from_object(Config)

db.init_app(app)
Migrate().init_app(app, db)


with app.app_context():
    from slackbot.v1 import bp as v1_bp

app.register_blueprint(v1_bp)

from models import SlackerModel,UrlModel,ParaModel
db.create_all()

return app
```

When it runs the create_app(),it would give me the error.
However,when I replace the line of `db.create_all()` by
 `@manager.command
def create_db():
    db.create_all()`
It doesn`t work!

Comment: In a perfect world every error message would have a link to a page that explains how to solve it. You just need to open it and find a solution. And of cause you would need to read the error message.

Comment: I tried it but doesn`t work.
app = create_app()
db.create_all(app=app)

Comment: Run `db.create_all()` with `with app.app_context():` context manager. It's described in documentation and link to it given in the error's message.

Comment: Are you sure your code is actually exactly like what you posted? Some indentations seem to be wrong

Comment: The indentations is right, perhaps something wrong when I pasted the code.

Comment: And I find the reason! In the model ,I import 'db' from the __init__.py of myapp, but it should be imported from my database......Thanks for all comments

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason! In the model.I imported 'db' from the init.py of myapp, but it should be imported from my database.